# NullPointerException during JSF navigation (MyFaces)

Tags: navigation, nullpointerexception, myfaces

I am getting a NullPointerException when trying to navigate from one page to another.
I have defined the navigation rule as usual in the faces-config.xml

But for some reason my webapp does not navigate to the next page. It stays on the current page, and I get what looks like an infinite loop of stack error messages.

The error stack I get from the Eclipse Console is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getViewMap(UIViewRoot.java:657)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getViewMap(UIViewRoot.java:645)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter._writeVariables(ErrorPageWriter.java:574)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter.debugHtml(ErrorPageWriter.java:288)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter.debugHtml(ErrorPageWriter.java:250)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.ErrorPageWriter.handleThrowable(ErrorPageWriter.java:417)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:274)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I have read other forum threads where this occurs, and they mention including (in the web.xml):

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I have already done this, but no luck.
Just to emphasise, I have been working on other JSF projects before and implemented page navigations without trouble. So I don't think it's a problem with my navigation rule.

The page I am trying to navigate to is called "login.jsp". The navigation rule looks like this:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>Global Rule to Login Page</display-name>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.jsf</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Any advice or suggestions would be gratefully received.

Many thanks,
Glen

Comment: Sorry, I figured out the problem, and completely forgot to update my issue. 
The problem was because I was trying to navigate to a jsp from a page (index.html) that was outside of the JSF environment. So fixed it by doing a url re-direct to a separate "index.jsf" page instead where I have moved the contents of "index.html" to.
The above has changed again, removing the need for the re-direct, but this was the cause of the problem. I hope it helps whoever gets stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some exception thrown and MyFaces prepares to render the corresponding error page. The NullPointerException seems to happen during rendering of the error page. So it looks like the original error is hidden somehow.

You could try to disable the MyFaces error handling to see if you get to the root cause somehow:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Hi chkal, thanks for the suggestion. 
No error page had been set for the webapp at this stage.